# Elasticsearch match query

Tags: database, elasticsearch, full-text-search

I'm searching for some text in a field. 
but the problem is whenever two documents contain all search tokens, the document which has more search tokens gets more points instead of the document that has less length.

My ElasticSearch index contains some names of foods. and I wanna search for some food in it.

The documents structure are like this
`{"text": "NAME OF FOOD"}`

Now I have two documents like

```
1: {"text": "Apple Syrup Apple Apple Syrup Apple Smoczyk's"}
2: {"text": "Apple Apple"}
```

If I search using this query

```
{
    "query": {
        
                "match": {
                    "text": {
                        "query": "Apple"
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

The first document comes first because contains more `Apple` in it.

which is not my expected result. I will be good that the second document gets more point because has `Apple` in it and its length is shorter then first one.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic search scoring gives weightage to term frequency , field length. In general shorter fields are scored higher but term frequency can offset it.

You can use unique filter to generate unique tokens for the text. This way multiple occurrence of same token will not effect the scoring.

**Mapping**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "unique", "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Analyze**

```
GET index29/_analyze
{
   "text": "Apple Apple",
   "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
}
```

**Result**

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "apple",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 5,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Only single token is generated even though apple appears twice.