# How to prevent elasticsearch fuzzy search from giving high score on repeated words

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fuzzy-search, fuzzy

I am working on elasticsearch and my query is

```
"query": {
    "match": {
      "NAME": {
        "query": "test query",
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
```

and I have tow string
1- "test query example elastic search"
2- "query example on elastic query and query"

the problem is when search for "test query" it returns the second string not the first one i guess because the elasticsearch gives the repeated words higher score so how to prevent it to give repeated words higher score and I want it a fuzzy search

Comment: You can use unique filter to remove duplicate tokens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158932/elasticsearch-match-query/69161581#69161581

Comment: Another option is try to disable term frequency (TF) stat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192860/elasticsearch-disable-term-frequency-scoring